# What Adi Shankaracharya said on scriptures being contradictory with reality?

Tags: adi-shankaracharya

Can you tell me Adi Shankaracharya view on Scriptures being Contradictary with Reality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: This Adi-Shankaracharya commentary on Gita 18.66]

This is Adi-Shankaracharya commentary on Geeta,18.66

As Adi Shankara said that even if Vedas say fire is cold and non luminous, such a statement cannot become valid and such a statement should be interpreted differently.
Even an uneducated illiterate knows that fire is hot. There are also statements like a hundred sayings of Vedas that a crow is white cannot make a crow white. These types of statements should be interpreted differently.